# how to redirect an application to error page when accessing without context root

Tags: java, web.xml, jboss-eap-7, contextroot

I am working on Jboss EAP 7 application server. My java application is configured with a context root of '/myapps' in jboss-web.xml file.

My issue here is when I access the application without context-root (till port number) I need to redirect the application to an error page (404 page) which is there in our application ear.
example : here is my app url - http://localhost:8102/myapps/login.
If I try to access the application like below URL it should redirect to a custom error jsp page.
http://localhost:8102/login.

Please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: The premise here seems a little flawed. You want to redirect to an error page that is within the context of your app without entering the context of your app?

Comment: No, I meant though I accessed the URL without context root till, is this possible to redirect to the application based on the port number of deployed application?